# res.set('Content-Type','image/jpg') is not working while serving image in node js

Tags: node.js, file, express, content-type, serving

res.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpg') is not working while serving us files in node js. Please take a look at code what is wrong with this code. I am getting the User Value and avatar binary value from the database but not able to see it on the browser.

http://localhost:3000/users/5f8930bba34fd3166c1b3f72/avatar and I am hitting this URL on the local server

```
router.get('/users/:id/avatar', async (req,res)=>{
        try {
            const user= await User.findById(req.params.id)
            if (!user || user.avatar){
                throw new Error('Avatar not found !!')
            } 
            res.set('Content-Type','image/jpg')
            res.send(user.avatar)
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(404).send()
        }
    })
```

Below are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.8",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "^2.0.3",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "validator": "^13.1.17"
  }
```

This is my user model

```
const userSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        trim:true,
        //unique:true,
    },
    age:{
        type:Number,
        default:0,
        validate(value){
            if(value<0){
                throw new Error('Age must be positive number')
            }
        }
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        trim:true,
        unique:true,
        lowercase:true,
        validate(value){
            if(!validator.isEmail(value)){
                throw new Error('Email is invalid')
            }
        }
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        minlength:7,
        trim:true,
        validate(value){
            if(value.toLowerCase().includes('password')){
                throw new Error('Password can not contain "password"');
            }
        }
    },

    tokens:[{
        token:{
            type:String,
            required:true
        }
    }],

    avatar:{
        type:Buffer
    }
    
},{
    timestamps:true
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `res.setHeader()`

```
res.setHeader('content-type', 'image/jpg');
```

Comment: i tried with res.setHeader('content-type', 'image/jpg'); But it wo'nt worked for me. i am sending my user model it would be more helpfull.

Comment: try `image/jpeg` rather than `image/jpg`

Comment: res.set('Content-Type','image/jpg'). it was working. William Answer worked also. The things were wrong with the code is if the condition which was not written correctly.

Comment: Thanks, William !!

Comment: best practice is to use `setHeader` all the time. please accept if you agree.

Answer (score 0):

No relation between `res.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpg')` and showing picture on the browser.

First you should add avatar .. if you using postman make new request with Post avatar then you can able to see it in the browser.

Hint: you have an error in if condition it should be :
`if (!user || !user.avatar)` instead of `if (!user || user.avatar)`

Answer (score -1):

Instead of:

```js
res.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpg')
```

Use:

```js
res.contentType("image/jpg")
```